# What does "self-deliverance" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *self-deliverance* mean?

What I don't get is, *self-deliverance* means different depending on a context used.
I mainly hear the word in music but not sure what it means.

Comment: Can you give us the context, so we can give you an answer?

Comment: Yes. Your tag is "meaning-in-context" and you don't give us any context! Please note: "in music" is not sufficient, please give an actual example, preferably with its URL>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At its origin, "self-deliverance" was mainly used in a religious context, when you "pray yourself out of" (sins, addiction, fear, ...), as a form of [**spiritual warfare**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritual_warfare).
To illustrate that, see [deliverance-music.org](http://www.deliverance-music.org/index.html), which has some [detailed explanations on self-deliverance](http://www.deliverance-music.org/deliverance-prayers.html), as well as some "deliverance musics".

But [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/self-deliverance) refers to it as just one word:

> "**suicide**", origin:1990-1995.

And that comes from the book "[Final Exit: The Practicalities of Self-Deliverance and Assisted Suicide for the Dying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Exit)".

> The book covers many aspects of planning and carrying out "self-deliverance", from the decision of whether and when one is ready to die, to the careful protection of anyone assisting one's preparations, to the legal and financial preparations for those one leaves behind.

So that expression might have a grimmer meaning today that it had before 1990.